# Leveling-up while Sanctuary is inaccessible in TVHM

Tags: borderlands-2

I have finished Normal mode, and went through True Vault Hunter Mode until Sanctuary lifts off. I now have a problem leveling up an reaching Sanctuary again. My sub missions are all done, except for those I can not complete yet. I can't level up in True Vault Hunter Mode because the missions must be turned into sanctuary. I struggle to get the Fast Travel Beacon without dying, so I don't have sanctuary on my map.
How can I level up quickly in this situation?

Comment: Are you saying you've went through True Vault Hunter Mode until when Sanctuary disappears?

Comment: Or you have just started TVHM?

Comment: After where you defeat willhelm the sanctuary moves to the sky.. All the loaders and stuff are between level 40 and 42 so I want to level up I did the missions but it must be turned in sanctuary.. And sanctuary isn't on my fast travel map becaus I need to activate the beacom but struggle to get the beacom and all the enimies in normal mode is too weak.. I want to level up quickly

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that your key problem is getting Sanctuary back.

I'm not clear on where you're getting stuck, but it's probably one of two big fights:

**1. The Gluttonous Thresher**

This is the fight to obtain the lunar beacon from the Hyperion dam area in [The Highlands - Outwash](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Highlands_-_Outwash). The [Gluttonous Thresher](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Gluttonous_Thresher) ate the beacon, and you have to beat it out of his carcass.

There is very much a *right way* to beating this monster thresher:

1. Run out into the area where it spawns.
2. As soon as you see or hear the thresher, perform a rapid strategic withdrawal. (i.e. Run away.) You want to get back through the door and out onto the big industrial "dock" area.

   If you're playing an Assassin or a Commando, use your action skill to distract the thresher to ease your getaway.
3. Once through the big door, find some cover. I use the big containers sitting on the left side of the dock as you exit the big door. (You could also cross the river on the retractable bridge and use the cover over there.)

   The thresher will chase after you, but will stop just past the big door, not going past those [K rail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_rail) barricades to one side of the big door. This is the key to this strategy: the cover you're using is outside the range of the thresher's tentacle attacks, and it is the tentacles that make the Gluttonous Thresher fight so difficult if you fight it where it initially spawned.

You will want a shock weapon in this fight, because the Gluttonous Thresher has a crazy-fast shield regeneration. You need to zap the shield away before you can start knocking its health back down again.

**2. The Robot Fight In Overlook**

After you get the beacon, you're asked to take it back to [Overlook](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Highlands#Overlook) where it's used to summon a fast-travel station.

This is also a tough fight. There's not as much of a single right way to fight this one, but again, cover is the key. I typically hide behind [the grinder](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Overlooked:_Shields_Up) while reloading and waiting for my shield to regenerate. It's good solid cover that you don't have to duck behind to get full benefit from, and you need to be nearby anyway to repair the beacon several times during the fight.

This strategy doesn't work as well against the loaders as it did against the Gluttonous Thresher. Primarily, this is because the robots drop into Overlook at two points, 90° from the grinder. This means that while you're fighting one cohort, the other — which you're protected from — is marching closer to the grinder. You thus have to keep running around behind the grinder to pound on each cohort separately, lest one of them overrun the grinder, denying you benefit of its cover.

I've gotten a lot of use out of my [Rolling Thunder](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Rolling_Thunder) grenade mod in situations like this. Any homing grenade can help, too, since you can just throw a bunch of them as you run behind cover, which keeps the robots busy while you recover.

Comment: OP says he has problems with Fast Travel Beacon, so he must be past that Thresher already. Is he retryable, and any good experience-wise?

Comment: @OrcJMR: I think my original read is correct, because what you're talking about is a Fast Travel *Station*, while the Beacon is the step before you get the Station. Still, I've addressed that second fight now, too.

Comment: Oh, right, you've got to *retrieve* the beacon first... Indeed, I was probably less accurate a guess than you!

Comment: But I want to level up to level 40 or 41 before fight the thresher because than I can go back to normal mode in sanctuary to get beter guns to fight of the thresher and those loaders I got a lot of golden keys.. But won't get stronger guns till I level up.. My strongest is a 63000 rpg.. And to go back and kill bandits or loaders takes too long I want to level up faster

Comment: You're backing yourself into a corner here. You want to level up fast but the fastest way to level up is to complete missions, not kill individual enemies. The only other way out of that trap you've made for yourself is to play through one of the DLCs. Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt is appropriate for your level, and since you're in the DLC, you won't need Sanctuary to finish missions. Tiny Tina's DLC is also good for a lot of XP.

Comment: @WarrenYoung That's only assuming he has the DLC's though.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk: Your point? OP says he wants to level up quickly without the ability to complete mainline missions. Solution: Add more missions outside the story line. If he's not willing to do that, he's stuck. Period.

Comment: @WarrenYoung My point is that the only solution you offered may not be available to the OP.

Comment: Thanks you but I connected a other pc with lan and kept him there so the threshers health doesn't regenerate and defeated him if got the beacom went to overlook but quit and saved